# Checking Permissions for S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to dealing with Amazon AWS/S3 and how it handles ACLs. I have set up a user account with access to a bucket and have working code to access my bucket, but my ultimate goal is to allow a user to see what permissions they have access to, letting them double check they actually have the permission nodes they need in the ACL.

Is there some way to programmatically check what permissions are available to me even when I have minimal ACL permissions?

I have tried GetACLRequest as follows:

```
var aclRequest = new GetACLRequest()
{
    BucketName = BucketName,
};
```

This works if I have the permission to get the ACL in the first place. However, standard security is to give least privilege to users, which I've already found often does not include the *s3:GetObjectAcl* node or *READ_ACP* user permission.

**tl:dr:** I want to make a list of the things I'm allowed to do on the bucket level and show it to the user when I don't have permission to get the ACL or trying to brute force a permission list.

Comment: If you have no permissions to query acl of a bucket then you can't list them.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was expecting, but I was hoping there was some way to do a dry run test somehow.

Comment: Permissions are often given on the IAM User or Bucket Policy, so ACLs are not the only way to gain access to objects in Amazon S3.